# Law of Sine proof

Tags: trigonometry

Below is the *Law of Sines* formula:

$\frac{\sin A}{a} = \frac{\sin B}{b} = \frac{\sin C}{c}$

[image]

And the proof is derived along the lines of:

$\sin B = \frac{h}{c}$ & $\sin C = \frac{h}{b}$

$c \sin B = h$ & $b \sin C = h$

$c \sin B = b \sin C$

and so on ..

Mathematically, I can understand this formula, but visually, it makes no intuitive sense to me.

How can "$c \sin B$" be equal to "$b \sin C$" when visually they have completely different proportions ?

Comment: How can $2\times6=4\times3$ when 2:6 and 4:3 are completely different proportions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's more intuitive this way: let $D$ be the point where the altitude meets $BC$.  Then $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle CDA$ are both similar to $\triangle CBA$.  In particular, $\angle B = \angle DAC$.

Now $\sin\angle B = \frac{h}{c}$ and $\cos\angle DAC = \frac{h}{b}$  So
$$
     c \sin\angle B = b \cos\angle DAC
$$
But the *co*-sine of an angle is the *sine* of its *co*-mplement.  So $\cos\angle DAC = \sin\angle C$, which means that
$$
    c \sin\angle B = b \cos\sin\angle C
$$
whence
$$
    \frac{c}{\sin\angle C} = \frac{b}{\sin\angle B}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to tell, that there's nothing I can do in order to make that proof more intuitive. It sometimes just happens that equations might be *mathematically* correct, but might not be intuitive (like it usually happens, for example, in probability).

The only thing I can do to help you, is to provide another proof (which - in the best case - might help you visualize the *Law of Sines*).

[image]

How does this picture help?

We are given a triangle $\triangle ABC$ inscribed in a circle. We want to find out $\sin(\angle BAC)$. Thus, we take $A$ to $A'$, such that $B, O, A'$ are colinear. Observe now that $$\angle BAC=\angle BA'C\implies \sin(\angle BAC)=\sin(\angle BA'C)=\frac a{2R}$$ Through permutation, we find out that 
$$\sin\alpha=\frac a{2R}\qquad\sin\beta=\frac b{2R}\qquad\sin\gamma=\frac c{2R}$$ Or

> $$\frac{a}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{b}{\sin\beta}=\frac c{\sin\gamma}=2R$$